# Chrome's modal dialog box stuck off screen. How to move it back permanently?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, dialog

Google Chrome throws up a modal dialog box once in a while. This is the box put up by js's `alert()` function.

Installing an extension also puts it up. So does this very Stack Exchange website if I hit "back" while writing a post like this one.

It's modal, so the browser's UI (the whole browser window, not just the current tab) is frozen while the dialog box is up.

My problem: the dialog box is off screen for me.  I can hit `<esc>` to dismiss it. I can hit `<tab> <enter>` to accept it. But I can't see it. The dialog box isn't represented in the Windows taskbar as a separate window, so I can't do the old Move trick to move it back onscreen.

I've tried obvious stuff like reinstalling the browser.

How do I get this dialog box to be visible again?

Comment: Try to temporarily change the monitor's resolution to another value and Apply. Questions: (1) Do you have more than one monitor? (2) Did you try the old Move trick by doing ALT+Space/M and then Enter? (try also alt-tab to position to Chrome)

Comment: Is it even possible to move it out of the window? Plus does it spawn there or is it somehow shifted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question appeared here on Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022839/chrome-modal-dialogs-dont-appear-locks-up-window

As it happens, disabling hardware acceleration for the browser did the trick. Clear the check from the checkbox at Settings / Advanced Settings / System / Use Hardware Acceleration.

Comment: does not work in all cases

Answer (score 7):

If the window is active, you can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> followed by <kbd>m</kbd>.  This will allow you to move the window with the arrow keys.

Comment: This solution worked for me when I had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2019 opening dialog windows off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the task bar and select 'cascade windows' or 'show windows stacked'. That re-arranges all the windows, including the modal dialog that this SO site created while I was writing this post :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to temporarily change the monitor's resolution to another value and do Apply.

If any problem, try also using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to position to Chrome.